# Synchronize batch applications deployed on different servers to process file by one server only

Tags: java, synchronization, spring-batch

I am writing a spring batch to read file from shared drive and load data into shared DB. This batch will be deployed/executed from 2 nodes(servers). I want to make sure the file is read by only one server and load data.

I am not finding anything concrete on internet. I have couple of ideas to handle this as mentioned below.
1. Use FileChannel tryLock to get a lock on file and move the file after reading it.
2. Maintain a table in shared DB to maintain a record say "fileReadJobExcution" with status as NULL initially. when batch application runs it will lookup into this table to get record with status null and try to update status as IN_PROGRESS. So whichever node(server) get updateCount > 0 will be allowed to read file from shared location and after successful that batch updates status back to NULL.

I am looking for if something already available in either in Spring batch or JAVA to handle multi node synchronization to a shared server.
Please help with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could either use [remote chunking](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#remoteChunking) or [partitioning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#partitioning) to achieve your objective.  From what you've described, I think partitioning would work best.

You could create a master `Step` to pull in your list of files, and then delegate the processing of those files to slave `Step` objects - either remotely or locally on different threads - passing the file name via the `ExecutionContext`.

The [Spring Batch Samples GitHub project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples) has some great examples, and I think you may find the [`partitionFileJob.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/partitionFileJob.xml) particularly helpful.

In particular, review the following `Bean` definitions from the sample project:

```xml
<job id="partitionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step">
        <partition step="step1" partitioner="partitioner">
            <handler grid-size="2" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="partitioner" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner">
        <property name="resources" value="classpath:data/iosample/input/delimited*.csv" />
</bean>

<bean id="itemReader" scope="step" autowire-candidate="false" parent="itemReaderParent">
        <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fileName]}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Philip for your suggestions. I have used partitioner and taskExecutors (sync & async) earlier as these are to make the processing concurrent and speed up the processing time. But my real problem is if I deploy my batch JAR on to 2 different servers. the file arrives on a shared drive which is mounted on both the servers where JAR is deployed. So on start up of batch job from respective machine would race to read file on the shared drive and insert duplicate data into DB.

Comment: Is your `ItemReader` reading the file names or the file contents themselves?

Comment: ItemReader reades the file contents of the file name sent by FilePartitioner through ExecutionContext.